# extract cdata using xslt

Tags: xslt

Below is the xml that has CDATA section

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<character>
<name>
<role>Indiana Jones</role>
<actor>Harrison Ford</actor>
<part>protagonist</part>
<![CDATA[  <film>Indiana Jones and the Kingdom of the Crystal Skull</film>]]>
</name>
</character>
```

For above xml i need to rip off the CDATA and add new element under the existing element "film" , so the final output will be :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<character>
<name>
<role>Indiana Jones</role>
<actor>Harrison Ford</actor>
<part>protagonist</part>
<film>Indiana Jones and the Kingdom of the Crystal Skull</film>
<Language>English</Language>
</name>
</character>
```

Is this can be done using XSLT?

Comment: Where does <Language>English</Language> come from in the output?  Perhaps it was supposed to be part of the input?

Answer (score 3):

A slightly modified identify function should work.

**Given this XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<character>
    <name>
        <role>Indiana Jones</role>
        <actor>Harrison Ford</actor>
        <part>protagonist</part>
        <![CDATA[  <film>Indiana Jones and the Kingdom of the Crystal Skull</film>]]>
    </name>
</character>
```

**Using this XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
            <xsl:value-of select="text()" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Will produce this output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<character>
   <name>
      <role>Indiana Jones</role>
      <actor>Harrison Ford</actor>
      <part>protagonist</part>
          <film>Indiana Jones and the Kingdom of the Crystal Skull</film>
    </name>
</character>
```

(Tested using Saxon-HE 9.3.0.5 in oXygen 12.2.)

Answer (score 2):

Since the `film` element in the CDATA block appears to be well-formed, you could use disable-output-escaping.  If you match of the name/text(), select value-of with DOE and then insert the `Language` element immediately following.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes"  />

<!--Identity template simply copies content forward -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="name/text()">
    <!--disable-output-escaping will prevent the "film" element from being escaped.
    Since it appears to be well-formed you should be safe, but no guarentees -->
    <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes" />
    <Language>English</Language>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: +1 If DOE is posible and there is a strong certainty that CDATA is wellformed

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve this which would give you some more control over the transformation is to use [Andrew Welsh LexEv XMLReader](http://andrewjwelch.com/lexev/). This gives you the possibility to process CDATA sections as markup among other things.

Comment: +1 Interesting solution. Note @Madhu that this is not an XSLT solution but works by supplying a different XML parser to the XSLT processor. May require a Java XSLT processor. If you have control over your XSLT environment enough to use this, it will take care of your parsing problems in a very complete way.

Answer (score 0):

First, the fact that your input XML has "CDATA" is in one sense irrelevant... the XSLT can't tell whether it's CDATA or not. What's key about your input XML is that you have escaped markup `<film>...</film>`, and you want to turn it into a real element.

If you know that the escaped element will always have a certain name ('film'), and you know where it occurs, you can strip it and replace it easily:

```
   <xsl:template match="text()[contains(., '&lt;film>')]">
      <film>
         <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(., '&lt;film>'),
              '&lt;/film>')"/>
      </film>
   </xsl:template>
```

If you don't know in advance where the escaped tags will occur and what the element names are, you could use XSLT 2.0's `<xsl:analyze-string>` to find and replace them. But as Alejandro pointed out, general parsing of XML using regular expressions can get very messy. It would only be feasible if you know the markup will be simple.

Comment: +1 a little more exact, in case there are multiple `name/text()`. Good defensive coding

Comment: rather you can add <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="substring-after(.,'&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;utf-8&quot;?&gt;')" />

Comment: +1 for the good explanation. One must mention that the general case requires a function like saxon:parse() -- probably we will soon have a standard one in the next version of F&O.

Comment: @Madhu No, that won't work because the XSLT doesn't see `<?xml version=...>`. It's not part of the source document tree. Even if it were, taking value-of `.` (which I assume to be `/`) would lose all the elements of the document: their tags would be absent from the output. Also, a big reason for the above is to avoid disable-output-escaping, which is a kludge that is usually avoidable if you treat markup as markup and text as text. XSLT processors aren't even required to honor d-o-e. In some environments, they can't.

Comment: @LarsH: I think you should test for `contains(.,'lt;film>')`. Also, I don't think is a good practice to recommend to parse XML with RegExp...

Comment: @Alejandro: thanks for catching the typo... I fixed it. Good point that parsing XML with regexp is not a good idea in general. Updated my answer accordingly. But don't you think it can be a lesser evil than d-o-e, especially if the markup is not too complex? and especially in situations where d-o-e won't work at all. One more tool in the toolchest, more of a last resort than a primary tool.

Comment: @LarsH: First, +1 for good answer for this specific case. I think that DOE or ussing RegExp for parsing are equaly "evil". Ja!

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with something similar and I found a good solution so I thought of sharing it with you, but this one is for `NSXMLParser`.

If you're using `NSXMLParser` there's a delegate method called `foundCDATA` which can look like this:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCDATA:(NSData *)CDATABlock{
    if (!parseElement) {
        return;
    }
    if (parsedElementData==nil) {
        parsedElementData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    }
    [parsedElementData appendData:CDATABlock];

    //Grabs the whole content in CDATABlock.
    NSMutableString *content = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:CDATABlock encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

 }
```

Now add [this prewritten class](https://gist.github.com/leighmcculloch/1202238) to your project. Then import it to the parser class you want to use it in:

`#import NSString_stripHTML`

Now simply you can add the following line to `foundCDATA`method:

```
NSString *strippedContent;
strippedContent = [content strippedHtml];
```

Now you will have the stripped text without any extra characters. You can substring whatever you want from this stripped text.