# How to remove span attribute in xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

how to How to remove span attribute in xslt .
here is my code
http://xsltransform.net/naZXpXG/2
**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<arttextnew>
<page>
<![CDATA[
<div class="section1"><div class="Normal">gment. <br /><br />ss <br /><br /> turns red.<br /><br /><span style="" font-weight:="" bold;''="">G.G. Saraswat, Delhi</span></div> </div>
]]>
</page>
</arttextnew>
```

XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <hmtl>
        <head>
          <title>New Version!</title>
        </head>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </hmtl>
    </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="span">
     ddddddddd===================
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**Expected output**

```
 &lt;div class="section1"&gt;&lt;div class="Normal"&gt;gment. &lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;ss &lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt; turns
        red.&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;span &gt;G.G. Saraswat, Delhi&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
        &lt;/div&gt;
```

how to remove is span tag **style="" font-weight:="" bold;''=""**

Comment: See if [extract cdata using xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3708055/205233) helps achieving the desired result.

Comment: You don't have a `<span>` element in your example input.  You do have *character data* that includes a substring having the lexical form of such an element, but that's not the same thing at all.