# XSLT1.0 Transform XML with &lt; &gt; and CDATA

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am getting an XML in following format:

```
<result>
    &lt;client id="IP2633100"&gt;
        &lt;quoteback name="CASE_ID"&gt;XXX1501076&lt;/quoteback&gt;
    &lt;/client&gt;
    &lt;order_dataset&gt;
        &lt;subjects&gt;
            &lt;subject id="S1"&gt;
                &lt;name type="primary"&gt;
                    &lt;first&gt;TEST&lt;/first&gt;
                    &lt;middle&gt;&lt;/middle&gt;
                    &lt;last&gt;TESTING&lt;/last&gt;
                    &lt;suffix&gt;&lt;/suffix&gt;
                &lt;/name&gt;
                &lt;birthdate&gt;12/12/1948&lt;/birthdate&gt;
                &lt;address type="mailing" ref="A2"/&gt;
                &lt;address type="risk" ref="A1"/&gt;
            &lt;/subject&gt;
        &lt;/subjects&gt;
        &lt;addresses&gt;
            &lt;address id="A1"&gt;
                &lt;street1&gt;TEST&lt;/street1&gt;
                &lt;apartment&gt;&lt;/apartment&gt;
                &lt;city&gt;LAKE WORTH&lt;/city&gt;
                &lt;state&gt;FL&lt;/state&gt;
                &lt;postalcode&gt;33467&lt;/postalcode&gt;
            &lt;/address&gt;
            &lt;address id="A2"&gt;
                &lt;street1&gt;TEST&lt;/street1&gt;
                &lt;apartment&gt;&lt;/apartment&gt;
                &lt;city&gt;LAKE WORTH&lt;/city&gt;
                &lt;state&gt;FL&lt;/state&gt;
                &lt;postalcode&gt;33467&lt;/postalcode&gt;
            &lt;/address&gt;
        &lt;/addresses&gt;
    &lt;/order_dataset&gt;
    &lt;product_results&gt;
        &lt;personal_property subject="TEST  TESTING"&gt;
            &lt;report format="CP XML"&gt;&lt;![CDATA[&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?&gt;
&lt;personal_property xmlns="http://cp.com/rules/client"&gt;
    &lt;admin&gt;
        &lt;quoteback name="CASE_ID"&gt;XXX1501076&lt;/quoteback&gt;
    &lt;/admin&gt;
    &lt;report&gt;
        &lt;summary&gt;
            &lt;total&gt;0&lt;/total&gt;
            &lt;subject&gt;0&lt;/subject&gt;
        &lt;/summary&gt;
        &lt;search_dataset&gt;
            &lt;subject id="S1" unit_number="1" classification="Report"&gt;
                &lt;name&gt;
                    &lt;first&gt;TEST&lt;/first&gt;
                    &lt;last&gt;TESTING&lt;/last&gt;
                &lt;/name&gt;
                &lt;birthdate&gt;12/12/1948&lt;/birthdate&gt;
            &lt;/subject&gt;
            &lt;address type="risk" id="A1"&gt;
                &lt;house&gt;00&lt;/house&gt;
                &lt;street1&gt;TEST&lt;/street1&gt;
                &lt;city&gt;LAKE WORTH&lt;/city&gt;
                &lt;state&gt;FL&lt;/state&gt;
                &lt;postalcode&gt;33467&lt;/postalcode&gt;
                &lt;zip4&gt;3818&lt;/zip4&gt;
            &lt;/address&gt;
        &lt;/search_dataset&gt;
    &lt;/report&gt;
&lt;/personal_property&gt;
]]&gt;&lt;/report&gt;
        &lt;/personal_property&gt;
    &lt;/product_results&gt;
</result>
```

I can only use XSLT1.0 to transform this data. Is there a way to transform this as shown below with:

1. replace `&lt;` and `&gt;` with < and >
2. remove the CDATA, xml version and xmlns lines but keep the value of the nodes below it.

Here is the expected output:

```
<result>
    <client id="IP2633100">
        <quoteback name="CASE_ID">XXX1501076</quoteback>
    </client>
    <order_dataset>
        <subjects>
            <subject id="S1">
                <name type="primary">
                    <first>TEST</first>
                    <middle></middle>
                    <last>TESTING</last>
                    <suffix></suffix>
                </name>
                <birthdate>12/12/1948</birthdate>
                <address type="mailing" ref="A2"/>
                <address type="risk" ref="A1"/>
            </subject>
        </subjects>
        <addresses>
            <address id="A1">
                <street1>TEST</street1>
                <apartment></apartment>
                <city>LAKE WORTH</city>
                <state>FL</state>
                <postalcode>33467</postalcode>
            </address>
            <address id="A2">
                <street1>TEST</street1>
                <apartment></apartment>
                <city>LAKE WORTH</city>
                <state>FL</state>
                <postalcode>33467</postalcode>
            </address>
        </addresses>
    </order_dataset>
    <product_results>
        <personal_property subject="TEST  TESTING">
            <report format="CP XML">
                <personal_property>
                    <admin>
                        <quoteback name="CASE_ID">XXX1501076</quoteback>
                    </admin>
                    <report>
                        <summary>
                            <total>0</total>
                            <subject>0</subject>
                        </summary>
                        <search_dataset>
                            <subject id="S1" unit_number="1" classification="Report">
                                <name>
                                    <first>TEST</first>
                                    <last>TESTING</last>
                                </name>
                                <birthdate>12/12/1948</birthdate>
                            </subject>
                            <address type="risk" id="A1">
                                <house>00</house>
                                <street1>TEST</street1>
                                <city>LAKE WORTH</city>
                                <state>FL</state>
                                <postalcode>33467</postalcode>
                                <zip4>3818</zip4>
                            </address>
                        </search_dataset>
                    </report>
                </personal_property>
            </report>
        </personal_property>
    </product_results>
</result>
```

I have tried this XSL transform:

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    
    <xsl:template match="result" name="firstPass">
        <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:variable name="firstPassOutput">
        <xsl:call-template name="firstPass"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    
    <xsl:template name="extractCDATA">
        <personal_property>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(., '&lt;personal_property xmlns=&quot;http://cp.com/rules/client&quot;>'),
              '&lt;/personal_property>')"/>
        </personal_property>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:variable name="cdataNodes">
        <xsl:call-template name="extractCDATA"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="$firstPassOutput" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$cdataNodes" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:transform>
```

It achieves first part but I need to find a way to get rid of CDATA and xml version and xmlns in the next lines BUT keep the nodes. Here is my XSL transform output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <client id="IP2633100">
        <quoteback name="CASE_ID">XXX1501076</quoteback>
    </client>
    <order_dataset>
        <subjects>
            <subject id="S1">
                <name type="primary">
                    <first>TEST</first>
                    <middle></middle>
                    <last>TESTING</last>
                    <suffix></suffix>
                </name>
                <birthdate>12/12/1948</birthdate>
                <address type="mailing" ref="A2"/>
                <address type="risk" ref="A1"/>
            </subject>
        </subjects>
        <addresses>
            <address id="A1">
                <street1>TEST</street1>
                <apartment></apartment>
                <city>LAKE WORTH</city>
                <state>FL</state>
                <postalcode>33467</postalcode>
            </address>
            <address id="A2">
                <street1>TEST</street1>
                <apartment></apartment>
                <city>LAKE WORTH</city>
                <state>FL</state>
                <postalcode>33467</postalcode>
            </address>
        </addresses>
    </order_dataset>
    <product_results>
        <personal_property subject="TEST  TESTING">
            <report format="CP XML"><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<personal_property xmlns="http://cp.com/rules/client">
    <admin>
        <quoteback name="CASE_ID">XXX1501076</quoteback>
    </admin>
    <report>
        <summary>
            <total>0</total>
            <subject>0</subject>
        </summary>
        <search_dataset>
            <subject id="S1" unit_number="1" classification="Report">
                <name>
                    <first>TEST</first>
                    <last>TESTING</last>
                </name>
                <birthdate>12/12/1948</birthdate>
            </subject>
            <address type="risk" id="A1">
                <house>00</house>
                <street1>TEST</street1>
                <city>LAKE WORTH</city>
                <state>FL</state>
                <postalcode>33467</postalcode>
                <zip4>3818</zip4>
            </address>
        </search_dataset>
    </report>
</personal_property>
]]></report>
        </personal_property>
    </product_results>

    <admin>
        <quoteback name="CASE_ID">XXX1501076</quoteback>
    </admin>
    <report>
        <summary>
            <total>0</total>
            <subject>0</subject>
        </summary>
        <search_dataset>
            <subject id="S1" unit_number="1" classification="Report">
                <name>
                    <first>TEST</first>
                    <last>TESTING</last>
                </name>
                <birthdate>12/12/1948</birthdate>
            </subject>
            <address type="risk" id="A1">
                <house>00</house>
                <street1>TEST</street1>
                <city>LAKE WORTH</city>
                <state>FL</state>
                <postalcode>33467</postalcode>
                <zip4>3818</zip4>
            </address>
        </search_dataset>
    </report>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to unescape XML characters with help of XSLT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463155/how-to-unescape-xml-characters-with-help-of-xslt)

Comment: @GSerg I have used this and this solves the first part. But I am not able to do the 2nd part where I want to remove the CDATA and xml version after CDATA but keep the nodes after it. I will update the question with what I have tried and what I see with it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [extract cdata using xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3708055/11683)

Comment: @GSerg I have already used part of the solution mentioned there, but the problem is to get the final output using a single XSLT1.0 file. I am looking further. I have been working on this problem for days and have looked at 100s of stackoverflow answers.

Comment: Are you using .NET for this?

Comment: No, its a complex 3rd party system, which is made in .NET so yes, the environment is .NET but we have to use their tool to make HTTP calls and then tranform the HTTP response using a single XSL transformation. I am checking with then if XSLT 3.0 can be used or can I use a custom program (which I can write in .NET) and do string manipulation to get the desired output. Still working on it the options.

Comment: What I am asking is when you are transforming the XML, are you using .NET's `XslCompiledTransform`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252552/discussion-between-pawan-pillai-and-gserg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this in steps (with each step saving the result to a file that will be processed by the next step):

**Step 1**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/result">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result 1**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
    <client id="IP2633100">
        <quoteback name="CASE_ID">XXX1501076</quoteback>
    </client>
    <order_dataset>
        <subjects>
            <subject id="S1">
                <name type="primary">
                    <first>TEST</first>
                    <middle></middle>
                    <last>TESTING</last>
                    <suffix></suffix>
                </name>
                <birthdate>12/12/1948</birthdate>
                <address type="mailing" ref="A2"/>
                <address type="risk" ref="A1"/>
            </subject>
        </subjects>
        <addresses>
            <address id="A1">
                <street1>TEST</street1>
                <apartment></apartment>
                <city>LAKE WORTH</city>
                <state>FL</state>
                <postalcode>33467</postalcode>
            </address>
            <address id="A2">
                <street1>TEST</street1>
                <apartment></apartment>
                <city>LAKE WORTH</city>
                <state>FL</state>
                <postalcode>33467</postalcode>
            </address>
        </addresses>
    </order_dataset>
    <product_results>
        <personal_property subject="TEST  TESTING">
            <report format="CP XML"><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<personal_property xmlns="http://cp.com/rules/client">
    <admin>
        <quoteback name="CASE_ID">XXX1501076</quoteback>
    </admin>
    <report>
        <summary>
            <total>0</total>
            <subject>0</subject>
        </summary>
        <search_dataset>
            <subject id="S1" unit_number="1" classification="Report">
                <name>
                    <first>TEST</first>
                    <last>TESTING</last>
                </name>
                <birthdate>12/12/1948</birthdate>
            </subject>
            <address type="risk" id="A1">
                <house>00</house>
                <street1>TEST</street1>
                <city>LAKE WORTH</city>
                <state>FL</state>
                <postalcode>33467</postalcode>
                <zip4>3818</zip4>
            </address>
        </search_dataset>
    </report>
</personal_property>
]]></report>
        </personal_property>
    </product_results>
</result>
```

**Step 2 (input is Result 1)**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="report">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(. , '>')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result 2**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
    <client id="IP2633100">
        <quoteback name="CASE_ID">XXX1501076</quoteback>
    </client>
    <order_dataset>
        <subjects>
            <subject id="S1">
                <name type="primary">
                    <first>TEST</first>
                    <middle/>
                    <last>TESTING</last>
                    <suffix/>
                </name>
                <birthdate>12/12/1948</birthdate>
                <address type="mailing" ref="A2"/>
                <address type="risk" ref="A1"/>
            </subject>
        </subjects>
        <addresses>
            <address id="A1">
                <street1>TEST</street1>
                <apartment/>
                <city>LAKE WORTH</city>
                <state>FL</state>
                <postalcode>33467</postalcode>
            </address>
            <address id="A2">
                <street1>TEST</street1>
                <apartment/>
                <city>LAKE WORTH</city>
                <state>FL</state>
                <postalcode>33467</postalcode>
            </address>
        </addresses>
    </order_dataset>
    <product_results>
        <personal_property subject="TEST  TESTING">
            <report format="CP XML">
<personal_property xmlns="http://cp.com/rules/client">
    <admin>
        <quoteback name="CASE_ID">XXX1501076</quoteback>
    </admin>
    <report>
        <summary>
            <total>0</total>
            <subject>0</subject>
        </summary>
        <search_dataset>
            <subject id="S1" unit_number="1" classification="Report">
                <name>
                    <first>TEST</first>
                    <last>TESTING</last>
                </name>
                <birthdate>12/12/1948</birthdate>
            </subject>
            <address type="risk" id="A1">
                <house>00</house>
                <street1>TEST</street1>
                <city>LAKE WORTH</city>
                <state>FL</state>
                <postalcode>33467</postalcode>
                <zip4>3818</zip4>
            </address>
        </search_dataset>
    </report>
</personal_property>
</report>
        </personal_property>
    </product_results>
</result>
```

**Step 3 (input is Result 2)**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns0="http://cp.com/rules/client">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ns0:*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result 3**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
    <client id="IP2633100">
        <quoteback name="CASE_ID">XXX1501076</quoteback>
    </client>
    <order_dataset>
        <subjects>
            <subject id="S1">
                <name type="primary">
                    <first>TEST</first>
                    <middle/>
                    <last>TESTING</last>
                    <suffix/>
                </name>
                <birthdate>12/12/1948</birthdate>
                <address type="mailing" ref="A2"/>
                <address type="risk" ref="A1"/>
            </subject>
        </subjects>
        <addresses>
            <address id="A1">
                <street1>TEST</street1>
                <apartment/>
                <city>LAKE WORTH</city>
                <state>FL</state>
                <postalcode>33467</postalcode>
            </address>
            <address id="A2">
                <street1>TEST</street1>
                <apartment/>
                <city>LAKE WORTH</city>
                <state>FL</state>
                <postalcode>33467</postalcode>
            </address>
        </addresses>
    </order_dataset>
    <product_results>
        <personal_property subject="TEST  TESTING">
            <report format="CP XML">
<personal_property>
    <admin>
        <quoteback name="CASE_ID">XXX1501076</quoteback>
    </admin>
    <report>
        <summary>
            <total>0</total>
            <subject>0</subject>
        </summary>
        <search_dataset>
            <subject id="S1" unit_number="1" classification="Report">
                <name>
                    <first>TEST</first>
                    <last>TESTING</last>
                </name>
                <birthdate>12/12/1948</birthdate>
            </subject>
            <address type="risk" id="A1">
                <house>00</house>
                <street1>TEST</street1>
                <city>LAKE WORTH</city>
                <state>FL</state>
                <postalcode>33467</postalcode>
                <zip4>3818</zip4>
            </address>
        </search_dataset>
    </report>
</personal_property>
</report>
        </personal_property>
    </product_results>
</result>
```

---

Note that this requires a processor that supports `disable-output-escaping`.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I have a solution in multiple steps but I have to do this with a single XSLT. There is some external program which only lets me run a single XSL transform file and I cannot do this in steps. Any thoughts with XSLT1.0?

Comment: Is it possible to have a master XSLT where I can add these transforms in sequence and get the final output?

Comment: No, not in XSLT 1.0. It is only possible with an XSLT 3.0 processor.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it is possible - in theory - to process the escaped code using string functions and create a corresponding XML output. But IMHO this would be a nightmare to try and do this in practice - and it would be quite unreliable too. Perhaps the best solution would be to get your data provider to use a format that can be worked with.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Can't you do the first transformation into `<xsl:variable>` and then the second to the output with XSLT 1.0?

Comment: @GSerg No. `disable-output-escaping` only works when the output tree is serialized - i.e. when writing to a file.

Comment: Thanks Michael and GSerg for the feedback. I will check with multistep and see if it can be used in any way. I will let you know in 24hrs.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I will go with this 3 step method using a workaround.